# data being insterted into DB multiple times when scanning file for marked words

Tags: java, mysql, file, loops, bufferedreader

I have an application that scans a text file for certain words, if these words are found a DB table is updated. im scanning through the file line by line for certain words like so

```
public void scanFile(File toBeScanned) {
    try {

        InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(toBeScanned);

        if (instream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
            String line;


            // read every line of the file into the line-variable, 1 line at the time
            do {
                line = buffreader.readLine();
                if (line.contains("word1"))
                    doInsert("word1", ourJavaTimestampObject , id ,"Test_Child");
                if (line.contains("word2"))
                    doInsert("word2", ourJavaTimestampObject, id ,"Test_Child");                    
                if (line.contains("word3"))
                    doInsert("word3", ourJavaTimestampObject, id, "Test_Child");

            } while (line != null);
```

my program is successfully picking up the words but is filling the database multiple times with them. eg. word1,word2,word2 are sent to DB and on second click the DB has word1,word2,word2,word1,word2,word2 and so on.

I call the scanFile method with a button click and any time that happens the words are re-entered ino the db.

I wish for my program to only insert each instance of a word once. so after the file has been read line by line perhaps the best course of action would be to empty the file ?? or maybe a different approach with my loop is needed

here is the insert method also

```
public void doInsert(String word, java.sql.Timestamp ourJavaTimestampObject, int userID , String child) {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("\n" +
                    "INSERT IGNORE INTO FLAGS (FLAG_WORD, FLAG_DATE, FLAG_USER, FLAG_CHILD)\n" +
                    "VALUES  ('" + word + "' , '" + ourJavaTimestampObject + "' , '" + userID + "','" + Register.child + "')");


            con.close();        

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }// end method insert
```

any advice much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for hours .

Comment: Which approach have you used ?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from question is that you don't want to read the content from same file again.

One way is to save the name of the file in the database (Assuming file name is unique) and check for unique file name in DB before insert.

Second way is to empty the file as suggested by you. Or alternatively, you can append header like "Already read" (at line 1) to the file which will serve as indicator that file has already being read by you.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT IGNORE` works with PRIMARY KEY, so make sure that column `FLAG_WORD` is set as the primary key so that the words are not duplicated.